# SublimeText2 auto complete wrong for ruby do block

Tags: ruby, sublimetext2

The auto complete for my ruby `do` blocks in SublimeText2 started auto completing this:
`downto(0) { nnn }` instead of `do..end`. I have not changed any settings recently so I am at a bit of a loss.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

maybe you should try `dob`, that is for `do..end` block snippet
or you can create this snippet your self:

```
<snippet>
<content><![CDATA[
do
  $1
end
]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>do</tabTrigger>
    <scope>source.ruby</scope>
    <description>do..end</description>
</snippet>
```

then you can use `do tab` to insert the do block which has no variable

Comment: Thanks @leonhart that creates a block with an `do |variable| ... end`, is there a way to not do that in rpsec? There is no `|variable|` after a `do` block in `it "rspec test" do ... end`

Comment: So maybe you could just create your own do snippet form Tools -> New Snippet.See my update.

Comment: I *think* the snippet file needs to be saved with the `.sublime-snippet` extension for this to work. IIRC it only worked after restarting Sublime (v2).

Comment: I first voted up this Q & A in 2015. Here we are in 2021, and it fixed Sublime for me again. Thanks, @leonhart and andreofthecape !

Answer (score 0):

In answer to andreofthecape's question and building on leonhart's answer:

In Sublime Text click on `Tools` then `New Snippet`

Paste in this code:

```
<snippet>
  <content><![CDATA[
do
  ${1:# use dob for do with variable}
end
]]></content>
  <tabTrigger>do</tabTrigger>
  <scope>source.ruby</scope>
  <description>do..end (no variable)</description>
</snippet>
```

Save as `do.sublime-snippet` in the suggested folder (`Packages/User`).

Try it out in a .rb file (type `do` and press the `tab` key).